# Logical Test: Arrows

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

What's the logic behind these patterns? Questions are from https://www.trytalentq.com's logical reasoning practice assessment. (available to all for free)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is

> ➡️⬅️➡️ because the rule is that each column is made from one cell of just vertical arrows, one of just horizontal and one of just diagonal, and in the cells with only horizontal arrows, the arrows alternate in opposite direction.

The second is

> ↘️↖️ because the rule is column-wise a column is made of a cell of 2 vertical lines, a cell of 1 vertical 1 horizontal lines and a cell of 2 diagonal lines.

The third

> one is **>>** because the rules are firstly that, per column, it is made of a cell with 4 arrows (3 pointing at the same direction 1 pointing the opposite), a cell with 4 arrows (2 pointing at the same direction and 2 pointing the opposite) and a cell with 2 arrows. Secondly, if we think column-wise the two arrows are identical (in terms of their order too) to the middle two arrows of the cell with three arrows pointing in the same direction.

Comment: nice one, thanks! Never thought about it the way you did. But I'm not sure I follow your reasoning for the last one, could you elaborate? I know its going to be two arrows but what makes you think it will be 5 and 5? What if the columns are alternating between 7 and 3, and 6 and 4?

Comment: I edited this, since I believed I made a mistake in the last question. It is in fact >>